# declare function's type as struct c++

Tags: c++, function, class, struct

So I have this class named User. Inside I have made a struct called flights and I want to make a function in this class to return a struct with the values of flights. Is that possible? Something like the follow. I know it doesn't work but is there a way?

```
   Class User
   {
       string name, surname...;
       struct flights
       {
          int miles;
          double cost;
        }
     struct add_miles(reads from another class);
   }
    struct User::add_miles()
    {
        return flights;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your requirement clearly but see my try:

```
 #include<iostream>

class User
   {
       //string name, surname...;
       public:
       struct flights
       {
          int miles;
          double cost;
        }myflights;
     struct flights  add_miles()
     {
        return myflights;

     }
};


   int main()
   {
       User me;
       me.myflights.miles=100;
       std::cout<<me.add_miles().miles;

   }
```

Comment: I think the OP is just looking to have `flights` as a return type.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to make `add_miles` return a `flights` struct rather than just a `struct`.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class User
{
    private:
        string name,
               surname;

    public:
        struct flights {
            int miles;
            double cost;
        };

        flights add_miles() {
            return flights();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    User u;
    User::flights f = u.add_miles();
    cout << f.miles << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour by returning `flights()` which contains uninitialized variables. I think OP's requirements only make sense if `User` also has a member variable of type `flights`, and `add_miles` returns that variable.